# How long the user stays on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to meassure how long the user stays on any page on a website. The challenge is that it needs to be done via **JavaScript**.

I Think the task can be accomplished by registering the time when the user load the page... attaching an onloadEvent, and doing the same on onbeforeunloadEvent...

**The Problem is onbeforeunload**

- You need to return something from onbeforeUnload.
- I need to make an ajax post to the database before the the user leave the page.

**beforeunload example**

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        saveFormData();
        document.location = 'http://localhost:52783/';
        (e || window.event).returnValue = null;
        return null;
    });

    function saveFormData() {
        document.location = 'http://localhost:52783/';
        console.log('saved');
    }
```

*This example works... but you need to return a dialog to confirm if the user wants to leave the page...*

Any other solution around the problem, what you guys think????

Comment: What if the user switches tabs?

Comment: This is tricky... Would saving these details to the browser's localStorage be a viable alternative?

Comment: Hi Mister Epic, to save this in a localstore wouldn't be necessary... I need to do an ajax post to save the information into our database... In the other hand Crescent Fresh, it the user switches tabs should trigger, since the user is not leaving the page.